# How to point heroku hosting to angular app and index.html in subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I'm new to deploying with heroku. Inside of my heroku repo, I have an nodejs + angular app where my `app.js` and all angular files are inside of a subdirectory called `app/`

I use grunt, and I can run my site locally without problem, and I go to `localhost:8000/app`. When I push to heroku, it goes through my `package.json` and runs the appropriate scripts to build the project. I have also already done

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

However, when I try

```
heroku open
```

The page says:

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

I believe this is because heroku isn't pointed to `app/index.html`, so there is no page to render. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: These are my heroku logs: http://textuploader.com/52qxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your web server configuration file (app.js/webserver.js or whatever you've named it) look like?

Here's a sample one using Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var path = require('path');
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/');
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/app'));



app.listen(port, function (err) {
  console.log('running server on port ' + port);
});
```

Heroku should have no trouble finding your index.html within your app folder if the above is configured properly.